# Is there a way to get auto table layout and specify a max width?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table that I never want to overflow. If it gets too big I'd prefer the `<td>` contents to wrap.

I know I can use `table-layout: fixed;` with `max-width` and `word-wrap: break-word;`, but then the columns are all equally sized, which isn't desirable because some of them have more content than others.

I know I can also use `width` on the `<th>` elements, but I don't always know ahead of time which columns will be the biggest.

Is there a way to have an auto-layout based on the content, but detect if the overall table would overflow and start wrapping at that point?

I'm open to using grid if that's the only way.

Comment: I take it you're not using Bootstrap? It uses a width on overall containers (at least the older version I'm using) which keeps things inside. I think you'd need something like that, that can change with media queries. Edit: I think that's the only way it would know it's about to overflow, right? If there's a hard limit somewhere.

Comment: Yeah no bootstrap. I think I'm going to end up just using media queries to ensure I have enough width before switching to a table view.